# Underground particle detector finds alien signal

Tags: story-identification, first-contact

I read a review in New Scientist about 5–10 years ago of a new sci-fi novel published by an author with an academic background – he may have been an astronomer or physicist – about someone working with an underground particle detector of some sort (neutrino?) who realises that a signal the detector picks up is from an alien intelligence.

I seem to remember that the author had some connection with Ireland – maybe nationality or was based at a university there.

Can anyone identify the author/book?

Comment: Not putting this as answer as I haven't read it but I suspect it may be The Trilisk Ruins by Michael McCloskey.  It does cover aliens and neutrinos do come up in the text.  But I didn't want to check further as I plan to read it :)  I also found this on newscientist and he advertises on there now and again.

Comment: @Dreamwalker: Thanks, but I'm fairly sure it wasn't that.  My recollection was that it was set in the "present day" and from the pov of one of the workers on the detector project.  Also, the author's bio definitely doesn't fit with what the NS review said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Late to the party here because I've been searching for the same book for years. I finally found it. It is called [***The Lure***](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/281468.The_Lure) by Bill Napier.

> A research station in Eastern Europe is suddenly bombarded with rhythmic bursts of subnuclear particles from the skies - a pattern so complex that it can only have come from a highly evolved intelligence. The scientists are amazed by the information that the messages reveal: secrets of an alien technology far in advance of our own. Should the signal be acknowledged and contact established? The world's superpowers have other ideas, and suddenly the scientists find themselves at the heart of a global conspiracy - on the run from forces determined to suppress the messages and what they contain. And what will be the effect on a world suddenly faced with unimaginable technological breakthrough...?

Comment: What about this book is a match to the question asked?

Comment: Bravo!  I'm sure this is the book + author.  Everything fits with what I remember from the review in New Scientist:  the author's background (astronomy) and connection with a Northern Ireland institution (Armagh Observatory) and the underground detector (mentioned in the book @google books).  Publication date (2002) fits too ...

Comment: Oh, and I remember the hardback's cover because I bought it for a friend (who's since mislaid it otherwise I wouldn't have been asking here).

Answer (score 10):

Could it be [Einstein's Bridge](http://faculty.washington.edu/jcramer/E_Bridge.html) by the physicist John Cramer? It took place in a world where the Superconducting Super Collider was actually built rather than being cancelled by Congress as in our world, and in the early 21st century physicists realize that some anomalies in SSC experiments are actually signals from an alien race in a "bubble universe" connected to our own, warning us that another Borg-like alien race called "The Hive" have also detected the SSC experiments leaking into their universe and are preparing to invade. Only thing that doesn't fit is that Cramer isn't from Ireland, but maybe it's possible he has Irish family background that was mentioned in the review, or that you're mixing up two different reviews or something.

Also, this novel was [reviewed in New Scientist](http://www.newscientist.com/article/mg16021605.600-time-tunnelling.html), though it was in 1998 so that's more than your estimate of 5-10 years ago.

Comment: +1 Sounds like that could be it, especially in view of the mention in the in review of it being based on the author's own academic work, which i distinctly remember.  1998 would explain why amazon have no record of a copy I ordered for a friend.  Anyway I've ordered a copy as it sounds worth a read regardless.